# First contact filmed like it was real life

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, first-contact, mockumentary

Hard to describe the film in the subject, sorry about that...

I remember watching this movie more than 10 years ago. Somehow (I don't remember the details) an asteroid is detected in a collision course to earth. I **think** that a signal is also detected and that's how some people start to think that there is some form of inteligence behind the asteoroid.

In the end, the asteroid is a transportation method and we, the humans end up destroing it (because we think it's going to crash instead of landing), which then causes an all out attack on earth. I remember the final scene, where a news anchor from CNN or something like that, says the last few words to the viewers, before humanity is wiped out of the cosmos.

The best part about the movie, is that it is filmed in a way that looks like it is actually happening right now.

Any of that rings a bell?

Comment: Did you see this movie on a TV station, or do you recall if it was on tape or in a theatre?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fairly close to a CBS TV movie from 1994 called [*Without Warning*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_Warning_%281994_film%29).

The latter part of the plot description:

> Over the next few tense minutes, nuclear weapons are launched to intercept these three objects successfully (although Washington is nearly hit).
>   With a sigh of relief, the news anchors report success. Simultaneously, the young French man and the girl die. But scientists are able to finally decipher their speech. It turns out they are each speaking a fragment of a message. When combined (although not complete as the assumed third survivor is never located), the message appears to be reciting of the message from the United Nations Secretary General that had been included on a special recording sent with the Voyager space probes.
>   Moments later, astronomers detect hundreds more asteroids, all heading towards Earth. As Sander Vanocur and his colleagues await the inevitable destruction of the planet, hearing reports of cities being destroyed worldwide, the wizened anchorman quotes from William Shakespeare: "The fault, dear Brutus, lies not within our stars, but within ourselves" as a rumble is heard and the picture cuts to static.
>   Most notable is the question of the aliens. Their nature and their reason for contacting Earth is never revealed, and they are never seen. Similarly the exact nature or reasoning of their "hello" message—the crashing of three meteor-like objects into Earth—is left a mystery, as is the intent and purpose of the follow-up vessel that is destroyed by the military. A third survivor of the original impacts is assumed throughout, but given the remote region in which the Chinese impact occurred, this individual is never located during the time frame of the film.