# Science Fiction programme, presented as a news programme, ends with asteroids heading for the Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv

I think this was an early 2000's or late 1990's TV programme presented as a one-off special news report.

An alien craft is identified and then shot down. It broadcasts a message which throughout the course of the programme is attempting to be translated.

Soon after an asteroid is detected heading for Earth, after a global effort the asteroid is destroyed. There is a moment of elation and then 20 asteroids are identified heading on the same trajectory.

At the same time the message is translated and it is shown to be a message of peace.

Any idea on the programme I am talking about? I can't remember if it was a UK or US production?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28971/first-contact-filmed-like-it-was-real-life

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be the 1994 CBS TV movie [*Without Warning*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111735/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2).

The story starts out with a fake TV program interrupted by bulletins about strange events -first reported as earthquakes, then as meteorite impacts in 3 places in the world.  Survivors are found at 2 of the locations, babbling unintelligibly.

Another object approaches the arctic, and is destroyed.  3 asteroids are then aimed at major cities (Washington, Moscow and Beijing) and are barely destroyed in time.  The babble of the survivors is determined to be an attempt to repeat back the message of peace sent on the Voyager spacecraft, but it is too late; hundreds of asteroids are on their way to targets all over Earth.

You can read a more complete plot summary [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_Warning_(1994_film)).  And the entire movie appears to be available on YouTube: